# One should love everyone's wife. Is it right grammatically?

Tags: possessives, reflexive-pronouns, parallelism

I want to know whether the sentence 
**one should love everyone's wife** is correct *grammatically* or not.

I think it's grammatically correct but meaning differs from the sentence

**One should love one's wife**.

My friend has been arguing with me that you shouldn't use **everyone's** in the sentence and you have to use only **one's**.

I said the former sentence means *a person should love everyone's wife* whereas the latter sentence means *a person should love his own wife* and both are grammatical.

I can't see anything wrong with the sentence *grammatically*.

Can you please tell me if I'm right or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> one should love everyone's wife

Well ... it **is** grammatically correct.  **However** it does not mean what you think it should mean. What this says is that you (or someone) should love **everyone else's** wives.  I'm sure [Casanova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giacomo_Casanova), [Don Juan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Juan), or Donald Trump would agree, but most other people would not.

If you want to say that every person should love his **own** wife, then you could say:

> Everyone should love his wife.

The challenge with this is that it is not gender-neutral, and nowadays in many places it's possible for same-sex couples to be married.  Unfortunately this leads to some awkward grammar, something like:

> Everyone should love their wife

Not as elegant as we might like, but we do the best we can.

**Edit** (March 15, 2019)

A better gender-neutral version would be:

> Everyone should love their **spouse**.

This takes into account marriages where neither partner considers the other the "wife".

Comment: The gender neutral version should be "Everyone should love their *spouse*", since "wife" is also very exclusive. (You don't need it to be plural, unless you're purposefully trying to include polygamy.)

Comment: @Nagendra Andrew is incorrect; saying *everyone else's* means that you are not saying you should love one's own wife. In fact, saying *one should love everyone else's wife* implies (not strongly, and dependent on context/tone) that one should *not* love one's own wife.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50322/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-one-should-love-everyones-wife-is-it-right-gram).

Comment: The singular they is perfectly grammatical and is attested at least as early as Shakespeare. Saying "Everyone should love their wives" is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 15):

You are right grammatically both sentences are correct but they differ in meaning.

Suppose there are three persons in the context : **a**,**b**,**c**

With the sentence **One should love one's wife**, you are saying that **a** should love his own wife.

But by the other sentence **one should love everyone's wife**, you are implying that **a** should love his own wife as well as **b**'s and **c**'s wives.

Comment: Both work, especially if his friend is a [swinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swinging_(sexual_practice))

Comment: ^ take it from batman

Answer (score 5):

(In light of the OP's recent edit)

Grammatically speaking, the sentence:

> One should love **everyone's wife**

is perfectly acceptable.

It means it is a good idea if "you" (one) love the ***wives*** of **everybody**. The modal verb *should* is often used for suggesting ideas, and giving advice.

One could disagree with the assertion, but not with its grammar.

The OP's friend recommends the following solution

> One should love **one's wife**

This is the better route to take, not only  morally, but semantically too. On the hand, it is also very formal, and distances the speaker from his or her listeners.

To paraphrase, you could say

> You should love **your wife**

As we know, in English, the determiner *you* is singular or plural, so this version works too.

> Every husband should love **his wife**

OR

> Every married person should love **his or her spouse**

Or using the singular "they"

> Everyone should love **their spouse**

As suggested in the [comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112716/one-should-love-everyones-wife-is-it-right-grammatically/112913#comment226718_112718) by @laurel

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly correct grammatically but I don't think it means what you want it to mean. Technically, and this exposes one of the relatively few shortcomings in the English language, to achieve the implied meaning in a grammatically sound way, one could say

> Everyone should love his or her wife.

Understandable, though, that this isn't what arises when following the path of least resistance.

Comment: @Nagendra - Lots of sentences are "grammatical" but that doesn't mean they mean what you think they mean, or intend them to mean. _Purple hedges lift heavy gentlemen by their tails_ is grammatical, but quite nonsensical. Same with _I can smell the color eleven_. If you're **only** interested in grammaticality without regard to meaning, then your question should at least acknowledge that you understand the true meaning of the sentence, and provide that meaning explicitly. Otherwise, you are inviting answers like this one.

Answer (score 2):

Coming in with a `tl;dr` response (apologies if similar to others):

> One should love **everyone's** wife

is a one-to-many relationship. While correct, this means one man should love every existing wife, and one should be very careful not to get caught.

> One should love **one's** wife

is one-to-one. Slightly less risky, yet still a decision not to be made lightly.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out one issue that most seem to miss. The phrase "One should love everyone's wife" implies that there is one wife shared by everyone.  Compare to the example from Fowler [yeah, sorry]: "Everyone was [or were] blowing their noses." The example itself speaks to the use of "was" vs. "were", but in both cases "nose" is plural. The ambiguity with number used in the verb causes ambiguity in the number for wives.